# How to set time delay for the loop, when everytime its get executed, in Javascript

Tags: html

I have tried with some code, but it's not working fine.

```js
  var canvas=document.getElementById('can');
  ctx=canvas.getContext('2d');
  canvas.width=1200;
  canvas.height=750;
  
  for (var x = 100; x <=900; x+=10) {
    linedraw(x);
   }
   function linedraw(n) {
    setTimeout(function(){
     ctx.moveTo(n,100);
    ctx.lineTo(n+20,100); 
    ctx.stroke();
   },1000 * 5);
  }
```

```html
<canvas id="can" style="background-color: gray"></canvas>
```

it's displaying a complete line after 5 seconds, but I need to display a part of line one by one for every 5 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go

```js
  var canvas=document.getElementById('can');
  ctx=canvas.getContext('2d');
  canvas.width=1200;
  canvas.height=750;
  
  for (var x = 100; x <=900; x+=10) {
    linedraw(x);
   }
   function linedraw(n) {
    setTimeout(function(){
     ctx.moveTo(n,100);
    ctx.lineTo(n+20,100); 
    ctx.stroke();
   },5000/900*n); // change here
  }
```

```html
<canvas id="can" style="background-color: gray"></canvas>
```

Comment: yes perfect answer!!!.. its clear, i need to make a small change.. Thank You @Dummy

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap a set timeinterval inside set timeout. In the below code you can change the time interval according to your need.

JS:

```
var canvas = $("#myCanvas")[0];
var c = canvas.getContext("2d");
var amount = 0;
var startX = 164;
var startY = 120;
var endX = 1094;
var endY = 120;

setTimeout(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        amount += 0.01; // change to alter duration
        if (amount > 1) amount = 1;
        c.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        c.strokeStyle = "black";
        c.lineWidth=1;
        c.strokeStyle="#707070";
        c.moveTo(startX, startY);
        // lerp : a  + (b - a) * f
        c.lineTo(startX + (endX - startX) * amount, startY + (endY - startY) * amount);
        c.stroke();
    }, 100);
}, 0);
```

HTML:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="1250" height="120"></canvas>
```

Comment: Yes, your answer is correct.. but i want this to happen with for loop.. can you please try.. @selvassn